# Java - Sudoku (backtracking) ' is place valid' method explanation needed.

Tags: java, backtracking, sudoku

I've this Sudoku code that's done using backtracking and I understand everything, except few lines of code which I ask to be explained. This is the whole code.

```
public class Sudoku {


    static int N = 9;


    static int grid[][] = { { 3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0 }, 
            { 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1 }, 
            { 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0 }, 
            { 9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5 }, 
            { 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0 }, 
            { 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4 }, 
            { 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0 } };

    static class Cell {

        int row, col;

        public Cell(int row, int col) {
            super();
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cell [row=" + row + ", col=" + col + "]";
        }
    };



    static boolean isValid(Cell cell, int value) {

        if (grid[cell.row][cell.col] != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot call for cell which already has a value");
        }


        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            if (grid[cell.row][c] == value)
                return false;
        }


        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
            if (grid[r][cell.col] == value)
                return false;
        }


        int x1 = 3 * (cell.row / 3);
        int y1 = 3 * (cell.col / 3);
        int x2 = x1 + 2;
        int y2 = y1 + 2;

        for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
            for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
                if (grid[x][y] == value)
                    return false;

        return true;
    }


    static Cell getNextCell(Cell cur) {

        int row = cur.row;
        int col = cur.col;


        col++;

        if (col > 8) {

            col = 0;
            row++;
        }


        if (row > 8)
            return null; 

        Cell next = new Cell(row, col);
        return next;
    }


    static boolean solve(Cell cur) {


        if (cur == null)
            return true;


        if (grid[cur.row][cur.col] != 0) {

            return solve(getNextCell(cur));
        }


        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

            boolean valid = isValid(cur, i);

            if (!valid)
                continue;


            grid[cur.row][cur.col] = i;


            boolean solved = solve(getNextCell(cur));

            if (solved)
                return true;
            else
                grid[cur.row][cur.col] = 0; 

        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean solved = solve(new Cell(0, 0));
        if (!solved) {
            System.out.println("SUDOKU cannot be solved.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("SOLUTION\n");
        printGrid(grid);
    }


    static void printGrid(int grid[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
                System.out.print(grid[row][col]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you go to `isValid` method I can't really understand this part. If someone can explain this part in detail and what exactly it does, that would be great. I saw this in many codes, but I still can not comprehend it.

```
        int x1 = 3 * (cell.row / 3);
        int y1 = 3 * (cell.col / 3);
        int x2 = x1 + 2;
        int y2 = y1 + 2;

        for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
            for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
                if (grid[x][y] == value)
                    return false;

        return true;
```

Comment: Have you tested these codes? Are they able to run without any exceptions?

Comment: Yeah, it works 100%.

Comment: I get you, but it does not. I have this code in eclipse and it works, but I get what you are referring to. This is not my code, that' why I'm asking these lines, cuz it doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: Nvm, I know what those codes are doing already. See my solution in a min

Comment: One hint for your next question: please take the time and format/indent all of your input properly. There is no point in wasting those many empty lines for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        int x1 = 3 * (cell.row / 3);
        int y1 = 3 * (cell.col / 3);
        int x2 = x1 + 2;
        int y2 = y1 + 2;

        for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
            for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
                if (grid[x][y] == value)
                    return false;

        return true;
```

This block of code locates the 3x3 box containing your current number. The nested loops checks that the given number does not exist in the 3x3 box.

---

If you are wondering why the formula (divide by 3 then multiply by 3) followed by adding of 2. Take a look:

If current row is `0..8`:

```
3 * (0 / 3) + 2 = 2 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 0 to 2)
3 * (1 / 3) + 2 = 2 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 0 to 2)
3 * (2 / 3) + 2 = 2 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 0 to 2)

3 * (3 / 3) + 2 = 5 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 3 to 5)
3 * (4 / 3) + 2 = 5 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 3 to 5)
3 * (5 / 3) + 2 = 5 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 3 to 5)

3 * (6 / 3) + 2 = 8 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 6 to 8)
3 * (7 / 3) + 2 = 8 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 6 to 8)
3 * (8 / 3) + 2 = 8 (read 3x3 box starting from pos 6 to 8)
```

Comment: But why x2 and y2 are even made ? And what does 11 has to do with the grid that's 3x3. Shouldn't for loop that's looping to x1 + 1 be enough ?

Comment: @Seinfeld It won't become 11. It always +2 because your grid array index always starts from 0. So if it is 2, it reads a 3x3 box (i.e.: index 0,1,2).

Comment: Oh, I finally get it. That's what made my some troubles. Thanks. GJ

Answer (score 1):

Assuming comments were meant to be useful to explain the code -

```
/** your row and column index are based on 0, 
 * and you evaluate the start index or lower bound for the 3x3 grid */
int x1 = 3 * (cell.row / 3);
int y1 = 3 * (cell.col / 3);
/** with the upper bound or the end index for the 3x3 grid 
 * at postion = initial + 2 */
int x2 = x1 + 2;
int y2 = y1 + 2;

/** Iterate through the 3x3 to validate the same element is not present
 * twice in the 3x3 inner grid */
for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
    for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
        if (grid[x][y] == value)
            return false; // false if its already there

return true;
```

For the lower and upper bound vaules, think of *grouping indexes 0-2, 3-5, 6-8* both in rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Simply spoken, *isValid()* checks those conditions that allow putting another value into a new position.

For example: it has a look into all the rows above/below; columns left/right and checks that the provided value isn't already there.

In other words: there are various conditions that need to be meet before "adding" a new number, and this method simply checks that board with that new value is still legit.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't get this multiplaying and division ... What does it do, line by line ? : )